# FOL for “x and y have exactly two common neighbors.”

Tags: first-order-logic

Let $E$ be a binary relation symbol representing adjacency in graphs. (That is, $$E(x, y)
means in a graph that “the vertices $x$ and $y$ are adjacent”.) Write a formula $\phi(x, y)$ in
the first-order logic over the language $L = (E)$ with equality expressing that

“$x$ and $y$ have exactly two common neighbors.”

Note that except logical symbols you may use only $E$ and $=$. (The phrases “$x$ and $y$
are adjacent” and “$x$ and $y$ are neighbors” have the same meaning.)

Will it be:

$$E(x,z) \land E(y,z) \land E(x,w) \land E(y,w) \to x=z,x=w,y=z,y=w$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. There are several problems with this.

First, you will need to quantify the $z$ and $w$. The formula should have $x$ and $y$ as free variables … but there should not be any other free variables.

Second, why would you set $x=z$? $x$ and $z$ are adjacent .. that does not mean they should be identical. Same for tge other identities you have.

Third, you should say that $z$ and $w$ are non-identical, so that you have at least two common neighbors. And to make that exactly two, say that nothing other than $z$ and $w$ is a common neighbor. And yes, you’ll need some conditional statement for that latter part, but you’ll also need an unconditionalized existential to state the very existence of $w$ and $z$

Comment: ∃z∃w(E(x,y)^E(z,w)) is this okay for x and y have two neighbors?

Comment: @Nomi No. z and w need to be the neighbors of x and y. So you need that z is the neighbor of x, that w is the neighbor of x, that z is the neighbor of y and that w is the neighbor of y.  It does not need to be the case that x and y are neighbors of each other. Same for z and w. Let's change the example a bit. Suppose I say that John and Claire have exactly two common parents.  Let those parents be D and M. So what do you now know? You know that D is parent of John as well as of Claire, and that M is parent of John, as well as of Claire. But obviously John is not parent of Claire or vice versa.

Comment: Thanks I will try and let you know

Comment: @Nomi  That's much better!  OK, so now you have that there exist 2 different objects z and w that are common neighbors of x and y... but that doesn't rule out any other such objects. That is, this statement would still be true if there would be 3, 4, or more objects that are neighbors common to x and y. So, you'll have to add to the statement you have something that will rule out any other objects ...

Comment: ^ ∀k( E(k, x)^E(k,y) ⇒ k = x ^ k=y) do i need to add another variable that represent everything else?

Comment: @Nomi  You're close! .. it should be $\land \forall v ((E(v,x) \land E(y,v)) \to (v = z \lor v = w))$  ... that is, any common neighr of $x$ and $y$ should be either $z$ or $w$ .. makes sense right?

Comment: yes it does. Thank you its done.

Answer (score 1):

No, that wouldn't be right. For instance, if your statement is correct, that implies that $x = y$, but one can easily draw a graph with four distinct vertices such that two of them share exactly two neighbours.

Hint: There are two components to this statement, that $x$ and $y$ share two neighbours, and that these are the only two neighbours they share. Try to write the first statement first.

Comment: will it be E(x, y)^E(z,w)